# Eclipse H2 database not connect

Tags: java, eclipse, h2, payara, dbeaver

I tried to connect H2 database using eclipse and when i try to connect it gives below error.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out: localhost:12345" [90067-200]
  connect timed out
  connect timed out
```

My connection settings

[image]

H2 Server,

[image]

Please help me to fixed this issue.

Comment: How did you start the h2 server? Can you share the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your h2 service has stopped. Check Services, and if it's not there, reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

You must start the h2 server with `-tcp` option.

For example:

```
java -cp h2-1.4.200.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpAllowOthers
```

You can also use extra options like:

```
java -cp h2-1.4.200.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -ifNotExists -baseDir <path-to-db-files>
```

Without `-tcp` you can get problems.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, but the only thing that seems to work is **restarting** my computer.

Here's a list of things that did **NOT** work:

1. refreshing the project and maven
2. closing and opening applications
3. adjusting the code

I could even see the database working fine in the H2 Console, but eclipse would not connect to it until I restarted my computer.

I logged this error many times:
"connection: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out: ..."

I restarted to connect to the database before lunch, and worked on my pc for an hour. It slept through lunch, then I had to restart my computer again to connect to the database in the afternoon.

Restart your PC before reinstalling anything.